Python Pandas: Select matching value from other table with comparison into each row without matching key
I have a structure of events happening for entities in table A.
Each event is linked to a process in table B.
Unfortunately I don't have the process ID in table A only a timestamp. Table B includes start and end of the process. Now I need to produce a query to find and add the process ID in table C.
Example
A
| Timestamp | Machine  |
| --------  | -------- |
| 18:01:01  |  1       |
| 18:01:02  |  1       |
| 18:01:02  |  2       |
| 18:01:03  |  1       |
| 18:01:03  |  2       |
| 18:01:07  |  1       |
...

B
| Process   | Machine  |  Start  |  End
| --------  | -------- | ------- | ------
| 1         |  1       | 18:01:00| 18:01:05  
| 2         |  2       | 18:01:01| 18:01:06
| 3         |  1       | 18:01:06| 18:01:15

C  (Machine = Machine && Timestamp >= Start && Timestamp <= End)
| Timestamp | Machine  | Process
| --------  | -------- | --------
| 18:01:01  |  1       | 1
| 18:01:02  |  1       | 1
| 18:01:02  |  2       | 2
| 18:01:03  |  1       | 1
| 18:01:03  |  2       | 2
| 18:01:07  |  1       | 3
...


I tried to use a join and filter it after, but table A is about 2,000,000 rows and table 2 about 8,000 going endlessy (via sqldf) or into a memory error (df.merge).
dfx = sqldf.run(
    """
            select * 
            from dfAGV  
            left join dfPE on dfAGV.time >= dfPE.created and 
            dfAGV.time<=dfPE.completed and dfAGV.machineID == dfPE.machineID            
        """
)

<- I cancelled this approach after 15 minutes runtime
pd.merge(dfAGV,dfPE,on='machineID', how='left')

goes to
"Unable to allocate 46.5 GiB for an array with shape (7, 892504663) and data type int64".

Any good idea to approach this?
